# Create GitHub action.yml file with different file path for .env file based on options provided by user

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I have a .yml file with GitHub Actions that have `workflow_dispatch` with some options:

```yaml
workflow_dispatch:
  inputs:
    webpack-build-mode:
      type: choice
      default: mob
      required: true
      description: 'Webpack build mode'
      options:
        - dev
        - test
        - production
```

In that file, I have my job where I am selecting an `.env` file:

```yaml
- name: Update API url
  uses: './.github/actions/replace-variable'
  with:
    orginal-variable: mydomain.com
    destination-variable: '${{ env.TARGET_DEV }}.mydomain'
    file-path: 'env/env.dev'
```

Based on options provided from `workflow_dispatch`, I want to change my `file-path` from `'env/env.dev'` to `'env/env.prod'`.
I am looking in docs, but did not found anything. My goal with this is to deploy on my dev env based on production env file.

Can I use any type of `if` statement here?

Comment: You can utilize options directly i.e. change option name from `production` to `prod` and use it to set that path i.e. `file-path: 'env/env.${{ inputs.webpack-build-mode }}'`.

Comment: aaa yes, that should work. I want to use `if` based on input and create second job, but this will be better i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `options` directly i.e. change option name from `production` to `prod` and use it to set the path:

```yaml
file-path: 'env/env.${{ inputs.webpack-build-mode }}'
```

BTW, `mob` is the default option but it's not included in the list of options. That needs to be added:

```yaml
workflow_dispatch:
  inputs:
    webpack-build-mode:
      type: choice
      default: mob
      required: true
      description: 'Webpack build mode'
      options:
        - mob
        - dev
        - test
        - prod
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [action-dotenv-to-setenv](https://github.com/c-py/action-dotenv-to-setenv) GitHub Action, as example you could have one env files for each environment and use like:

```
  - name: Configure ${{ inputs.webpack-build-mode }} environment
    uses: c-py/action-dotenv-to-setenv@v2
    with:
      env-file: ./env/env.${{ inputs.webpack-build-mode }}
```